# Some JS code missing after Cordova run

Tags: javascript, cordova, phpstorm

I have some functions in `application.js` file included in HTML files via `<script>` tag. The IDE I am using is PhpStorm and using Cordova platform.

I use the command `cordova run android --device` to run the app directly on my Android device connected over WiFi.

The weird problem is when I run some JS functions, var initialization and call to the functions fo missing from the .js file. When I press <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd> in PhpStorm, it asks "Undo reload from disk?" and on clicking "OK", the missing code appears back.

Note: The code goes missing after **LAUNCH SUCCESS** appear in the terminal.

What could be the problem?

Comment: looks like cordove live reload is changing the files for some reason... haven't ever heard of such issues

Answer (score 0):

Could not figure out the reason why it happened, but the issue disappeared after removing and adding again the platform Android.

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```

The issue might occur again, I believe.